# How to revert git working repo initiated over bare repo?

Tags: git

I had a bare repo on a windows 10 folder. This bare repo has been used for some time and has dozens of commits. Accidentally, today, I ran

```
git status
fatal: this operation must be run in a work tree
git init
git add .
git commit -m "initial commit"
```

on it.

Thus I created a working repo over my previous bare repo. Now if I try to clone it I end up cloning the files from the working repo, which are the original files from the bare repo, which are not working files.

I want to delete this working repo I initiated while keeping the original bare repo untouched.

How should I do that ? I can see the files that I changed by looking at their timestamps, but should that be enough ? I'm afraid I might've overwritten something and deleting will jeopardize it all.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve. If you want to start over and you haven't pushed your changes to any remotes, you can just delete the .git directory for the repo.

Comment: But it was a bare repo beforehand. If I just delete the .git, I'll delete both the new working repo (which is empty trash) and the old bare repo. correct ?

Comment: You'll effectively delete git's tracking of  the repo. You can then keep what files you want, and re-run the git commands when you're ready.

Comment: But as a *bare* repo there are no files. you see ? I edited the question for clarification.

Comment: You can have files in a bare repo (on your file system); they're just not tracked by git yet.

Comment: You can't have two repos I'm the exact same directory. Unless you're saying one is physically nested under the other. Is that it?

Comment: I really don't know how to answer to your last question. I just ran the commands sequentially. Let me input another command I ran and see if that clarifies

Comment: If you don't want to delete your .git, you should be about to do "git reset HEAD^".

Comment: I tried that, now on the status I get: nothing to `commit, working tree clean`. there shouldn't be a working tree anymore though, right ?

Comment: It doesn't matter for your purposes. If you have no commits, when you do a 'git status', wasn't that your goal? ... Alternatively, you can delete the .git and run 'git init' again. I think you're making this too complicated.

Answer (score 1):

A "bare" repository looks like this:

```
$ git init --bare
Initialized empty Git repository in .../tmp/tbare/
$ ls -AF
HEAD            config          hooks/          objects/
branches/       description     info/           refs/
```

You may have a few additional files and/or directories, including `index` and `logs`, depending on what you have been doing with it.

Running `git init` in this bare repository adds a `.git` directory, so that you now have *two* Git repositories: the bare one in the current directory, and the `.git` non-bare one for which the current directory is a work-tree:

```
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in .../tmp/tbare/.git/
$ ls -AF
.git/           branches/       description     info/           refs/
HEAD            config          hooks/          objects/
```

Nothing has changed in the *bare* repository, but now `git ...` finds the `.git` directory and uses that.  Should you wish to use the bare repository, you must tell Git not to look at `.git` but rather at `.`:

```
$ git --git-dir=. status
fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree
$ git status | head -1
On branch master
```

If you simply *remove* the `.git` directory, Git goes back to not being able to find `.git` and instead using `.` which gets it the bare repository:

```
$ rm -rf .git
$ ls -AF
HEAD            config          hooks/          objects/
branches/       description     info/           refs/
$ git status
fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree
```

Everything is now back the way it was before—you've deleted the additional repository (and all of its commits, since they contained nothing useful that was not also contained in its work-tree, which was the original repository).

For warm fuzzy feelings, before removing `.git`, run `git --git-dir=. log --all --decorate --oneline --graph`.  You should see all the commits that the bare repository held before you did any of this.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer was very very elusive. Although something weird happens. `git --git-dir=. status` yields `fatal: not a git repository: '.'` whereas `git --work-tree=. log --all --decorate --oneline --graph` yields the expected results. In fact, when I run `rm -rf .git` and then `git status` it yields `fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`. Which is odd. It might be worth saying that this bare repo is a couple of years old.

Comment: Oops, that last "warm fuzzy" line should have had `--git-dir=.` in it, not `--work-tree=.`. This all assumes you're still in the bare repository, and that `ls` produces the kind of listing I showed above. (Also I don't think you want the word ["elusive"](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/elusive) :-) )

Comment: I definitely meant enlightening! Well the first `ls` does not produce the expected result, it only shows `.git`

Comment: Oh, that's worrisome, it means the bare repository's files are all gone. Note that if you try to clone the bare repo you'll probably get the non-bare repo you created, though. If that has in it all the files from the bare repo, you can extract them, then check to see if the bare repo extraction worked...